# LaTex Error: Environment equation* undefined

Tags: equations

[image]

I am trying to work on a Poisson problem (BVP) which looks like the pic above.
However, when I executed my codes as below, the compiler showed that

```
"LaTex Error: Environment equation* undefined."
```

I don't know why?

```
\begin{equation*}
(PE)\hspace{0.3cm}\left\{\begin{matrix}
\hspace{0.3cm} -\Delta u=f & in\hspace{0.1cm} \Omega  \\
\hspace{0.3cm} u(x)=0 & on \hspace{0.1cm} \partial \Omega
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Did you load amsmath or mathtools?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It appears you're missing `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: Once `mathtools` is loaded, you might be interested in the `cases` environment(s).

Comment: @Johannes_B `amsmath` also has `cases`, for that matter.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed, but mathtools provides some extensions to amsmath, that goes for cases as well. :-)

Answer (score 29):

Adding

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to the preamble solved the problem.

Comment: So, if I want to say personal gratitude to whom helped me to solve the problem, it is better to "Add Comment". right?